# Honor aliases when using sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have two aliases set up in my `.bash_profile`. I want `sudo` to honor both of them:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export EDITOR=emacs
...
alias yum="dnf"
alias ssh="ssh -2"
...
```

I know how to tell `sudo` to honor my environment (`-E`), but I can't find the option for aliases. Searching the man page for *`alias`* results in *`Pattern not found`*.

How do I tell `sudo` to honor my aliases?

Thanks in advance.

---

I'm trying to avoid these annoying messages due to Fedora changing commands:

```
$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for: 
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf update'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo can't really "honor" aliases, as they're a shell-specific feature – the only way sudo could know about them if it was taught how to read `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.cshrc`... by itself.

For ordinary aliases, you can trick the shell itself into expanding them when followed by `sudo`:

```
alias sudo="sudo "
```

(It's sort-of documented somewhere.)

But for functions, there is nothing similar; you'll have to use the interactive `sudo -sE` mode instead.

Comment: Thanks Grawity. I'll need  some time to get back to Fedora for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to your problem is to put your aliases, as usual, in your file `/home/YourName/.bash_aliases`, and then to link that file into root's home directory:

```
      sudo ln -s /home/YourName/.bash_aliases /root/.bash_aliases
```

This *should* work automatically because most distros have these lines in the `.bashrc` file you are given by default,

```
      if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
          . ~/.bash_aliases
      fi
```

If you do not have them, it is easy to add them.